# Binomial LASSO Regression - p-values and coefficients

Tags: p-value, lasso, binary-data

I would like to know how to select the final variables in (cv.glmnet) LASSO by passing the lm command (similar to the link below) but for **binary outcome with binary predictors.**

Thanks a lot.

Link to obtaining p values of final variables in LASSO with continuous outcome:
[LASSO Regression - p-values and coefficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410173/lasso-regression-p-values-and-coefficients)

```
data <- read.csv(file = 'X.csv')
train_df <- na.omit(data)

# Predictors
xfactors<-model.matrix(Outcome ~ ., data=train_df)[,-1]
xfactors

yfactors<- train_df$Outcome
yfactors  

#create dummy variable matrix
x<-as.matrix(data.frame(xfactors)) 
x


CV = cv.glmnet(x, y=yfactors, alpha=1, family = "binomial", 
               type.measure = "class", nlambda = 100, nfolds = 10, intercept=TRUE)

CV = glmnet(x, y=yfactors, alpha = 1, family = "binomial",
             lambda = CV$lambda.min)

W <- as.matrix(coef(CV))
W

keep_X <- rownames(W)[W!=0]
keep_X <- keep_X[!keep_X == "(Intercept)"]
x <- x[,keep_X]

summary(lm(yfactors~x))

#### Getting this error below

Call:
lm(formula = yfactors ~ x)

Residuals:
Error in quantile.default(resid) : (unordered) factors are not allowed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
  using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(r, 2) : ‘^’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: For a binary outcome, use function glm, not function lm. That might solve the issue, but not sure, because the code is not reproducible. (Note that computing p-values after performing variable selection makes the p-values invalid.)

Comment: Thanks @MarjoleinFokkema

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to upvote the comment, the option isn't available for me. @MarjoleinFokkema

Comment: @MarjoleinFokkema, Can you kindly help me with this question at link: (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/514762/can-i-run-glm-after-mi-with-elastic-net-non-zeroed-coefficients-from-miselect)