# Can I run glm after MI with Elastic-Net non-zeroed coefficients from 'miselect'?

Tags: cross-validation, multiple-imputation, elastic-net

I have data with n = 80 and 10 predictors, and ran MI using MICE, followed by Variable Selection for Multiply Imputed Data using ‘miselect’ and finally have 4 non-zeroed coefficients.

Since statistical inference can be done only after bootstrapping.

Can I run glm on the the 4 variables with non-zero coefficients using with() and pool estimates?

Thanks a lot.

Code below.

```
Data = read.csv(file = 'Data.csv')

Data$Y <- as.factor(Data$Y)

#Convert to numerics
Data $X1 <- as.numeric(Data $X1)
Data $X2 <- as.numeric(Data $X2)
Data $X3 <- as.numeric(Data $X3)
Data $X4 <- as.numeric(Data $X4)
Data $X5 <- as.numeric(Data $X5)
Data $X6 <- as.numeric(Data $X6)
Data $X7 <- as.numeric(Data $X7)
Data $X8 <- as.numeric(Data $X8)
Data $X9 <- as.numeric(Data $X9)
Data $X10 <- as.numeric(Data $X10)

# Imputation
mids <- mice(Data, m=5, maxit = 38, print =  T, seed = 380482, printFlag=T)

# Plotting to check for convergence
plot(mids2)

# Plot distribution of imputations
stripplot(mids2, pch=20, cex=1.2)

###### Regularized regression:

# Generate list of completed data.frames
dfs <- lapply(1:5, function(i) complete(mids, action = i))

# Generate list of imputed design matrices and imputed responses
x <- list()
y <- list()
for (i in 1:5) {
  x[[i]] <- as.matrix(dfs[[i]][, paste0("X", 1:10)])
  y[[i]] <- dfs[[i]]$Y
}


# Calculate observational weights
weights  <- 1 - rowMeans(is.na(Data))
pf       <- rep(1, 10)
adWeight <- rep(1, 10)
alpha    <- c(.5 , 1)

# Since 'Y' is a binary variable, we use 'family = "binomial"'
fit <- cv.saenet(x, y, pf, adWeight, weights, family = "binomial",
                 alpha = alpha, nfolds = 5)

coef(fit)

adWeight <- 1 / (abs(coef(fit)[-1]) + 1 / nrow(Data))

afit <- cv.saenet(x, y, pf, adWeight, weights, family = "binomial",
                  alpha = alpha, nfolds = 5)

coef(afit)

> coef(afit)
(Intercept)          X1          X2          X3          X4          X5          X6          X7          X8          X9         X10 
 8.43339057  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000 -5.76423658  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.62928026 -0.09510549  0.00000000  0.50879124
```

Answer (score 2):

One should not perform exploration/variable selection and inference on the same sample of observations. The $p$ values are no longer valid (i.e., too low) if you use the exact same data to select the predictor variables, first. For performing hypothesis tests (inference), you need to have specified *a-priori* hypotheses. From these data, you have extracted the hypothesis that the four variables are predictive of the response. If you collect a new sample from the same population, you can then perform inference by applying `glm()` to those observations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment @MarjoleinFokkema . So, despite the small n and the need to minimize over fitting, should I split the data and and perfom cv.saenet on the training data and then glm on the testing data? Iam sorry, not able to upvote yet till I reach 15 reputations.

Comment: @User1121 Sorry, made a small typo earlier, corrected now. That would be a possibility, splitting the data, but power may be low. If you impute data before making the split, make sure you do not use the outcome variable in imputation. See e.g., Jaeger, B. C., Tierney, N. J., & Simon, N. R. (2020). When to Impute? Imputation before and during cross-validation. arXiv preprint arXiv:2010.00718.

Comment: I am thankful for your help. Much appreciated. @MarjoleinFokkema

Comment: Nice answer (+1) @User1121 If this answer is helpful please consider upvoting it and if it resolves your question, marking it as the accepted answer.