# Comparing AUC and classification loss for binary outcome in LASSO cross validation

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, lasso

I'm analyzing biological data where I'd like to see the impact of scaled gene expression on the classification of the sample. I binarized the response variable as `0` and `1` and used lasso with cross-validation. My goal is inference rather than prediction at this point.

I compared two different `type.measure` parameters (`auc` and `class`) in `cv.glmnet` function and plotted coefficient estimates in a scatter plot:

[image: coefficient-comparison]

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the documentation suggests both methods can be suitable for binary classification problems. I'm trying to understand the differences I see here. When using misclassification error (`class`) loss function, more variables shink to zero compared to the area under the ROC curve (`auc`) What is the reason for this different behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Measuring accuracy of a logistic regression-based model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18178/measuring-accuracy-of-a-logistic-regression-based-model)

Comment: I got some great insights from that link, but I don't think it necessarily answers my question. I'm trying to get a sense of why misclassification loss function is shrinking more variables, where in essence, the ROC curve is drawn using the frequency of true and false predictions. Is the situation I'm looking at here that the accuracy of the model measured at a certain point as opposed to the entire continuum of the possible values (ie a fixed (average?) point on ROC curve versus the whole area under the curve?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point is that [accuracy is not really "suitable for binary classification problems"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/28500) despite its frequent use as a criterion in model evaluation.

In an important sense there is no single "accuracy" measure as it depends on selection of a particular probability cutoff for assigning class membership. For binary classification this selection is often hidden from  view (as it seems to be in `cv.glmnet()` when `class` is selected as the criterion) and set at a value of p = 0.5; that is, class membership is assigned to whichever class has the highest probability. That's only appropriate if you assign the same cost to false-positive and false-negative errors. Other relative costs would lead to different choices of the probability cutoff. See [this recent page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/478494/28500) for an introduction and links to further discussion about selecting cutoffs.

So your sense expressed in a comment is correct: the difference is that AUC examines the whole range of potential false-positive versus false-negative tradeoffs versus the single choice imposed by the p = 0.5 class-assignment threshold. As [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18178/28500) discusses, `auc` is thus preferable to `class` as a criterion for comparing models as you are effectively doing with cross validation.

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/28500) describes how the best way to evaluate such models is with a proper [scoring rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule), which is optimized when you have identified the correct probability model. The `deviance` criterion in `cv.glmnet()` (the default for logistic regression) is equivalent to a strictly proper log-loss scoring rule. That may be bit more sensitive than `auc` for distinguishing among models; see [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/339919/28500).

I can't say with certainty why the `class` criterion maintains fewer genes in the final model than does `auc`. I suspect that's because the `class` criterion is less sensitive to distinguishing among models, which is what you're doing when you try to minimize over a range of penalty values, so it ends up with larger weights on fewer predictors. But that's an intuitive heuristic argument with no formal basis.

A final note: inference following LASSO is not straightforward. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/291622/28500) for some discussion. With gene-expression data you typically have a large number of correlated potential predictors, among which LASSO will make choices that can be very data dependent. So even if you calculate p-values and CI properly that doesn't mean you have identified "the most important" genes for the classification, just a particular set that is justifiable. Try repeating the modeling on multiple bootstrapped samples of the data to gauge how stable the gene-selection process is.

Comment: would you then suggest one should use `type = "deviance"` over `auc` even with binary outcomes as it equals a proper log-loss scoring? This of course also relates to my question, you refer to in this answer?

Comment: @Thomas yes I think that's the safest choice from what's available built-in to `cv.glmnet()`; it's the default. Log-loss is far from the only proper scoring rule, but it comes directly from the maximum-likelihood calculations used to solve the logistic regression. It puts a lot of weight on extreme cases. In principle you could use any proper scoring rule for choosing the logistic-regression penalty by cross validation, although you would have to adapt the cross-validation code yourself.

Comment: Interesting. I will definitely give it a shot to compare models. Can you readily obtain the log-loss once the `cv.glmnet` has run then? Thank you.

Comment: @Thomas yes, it's [equivalent to the deviance error criterion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/157930/28500). The cross-validated error (by whatever criterion was chosen) as a function of $\lambda$ is in the `cvm` part of the object returned by `cv.glmnet()`. Be carful when comparing models with different numbers of parameters, however; see the [Akaike Information Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) and its [relationship with deviance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/191235/28500).

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer. Do you have a recommendation on how to proceed if bootstrapping reveals unstable models? Since we don't know which correlated genes are important, is it better to be inclusive and consider all the estimated non zero coefficients in different models?

Comment: @Atakan this is an inherent problem with LASSO. How you will be using the results matters. Signaling pathways are most important; multiple genes can be proxies for the same altered pathway. For a test to distinguish 2 classes, just using the original LASSO model would be fine as which particular proxy is chosen doesn't matter much.  As a guide to further experiments you want to examine a wider set of genes. You might consider instead the `limma` Bioconductor function (or its more recent extensions) to gauge differentially expressed genes, together with pathway analysis.